# Can not create tunnel via staging server

Tags: tunnel

I am trying to create a tunnel directly with ssh command.
My scenario works well when I do following configuration

host: A
pass:**
Tunnel Section in Putty : 6001:HostXX:22
Open this session now

login with 127.0.0.1 port 6001 and username/password for HOSTXX
Tunnel Section in Putty : 20333:DBHOST:54666

This work well when I start putty session individually for both sessions.

I am trying to find a solution where I could do this tunneling directly using one ssh command.

I tried following but did not work.

```
ssh -f HostA -l username -L 6001:10.54.172.68:22 \ ssh -p 6001 -N 127.0.0.1 -l username1 -i username1.pem -L 20333:dbhost:54666

ssh -fN HostA -l username -L 6001:10.54.172.68:22 \ ssh -fN -p 6001 -N 127.0.0.1 -l username1 -i username1.pem -L 20333:dbhost:54666
```

I also tried from cmd running these commands individually but not helping me.
Please suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

Tunneling works better as a proxy.  All you should have to do to create the tunnel to ssh to servers on the other side of the tunnel is:

Create tunnel:

```
ssh -qCfND <PORT> username@tunnelserver
```

Where `<PORT>` is any port you want to assign. 6001 would work fine.  The switches are `-q` for Quiet Mode.  `C` for Compression.  `f` for ssh to go to the background.  `N` for just forwarding the port.  `D` for port binding.

Then to ssh to any server on the other side it is:

```
ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -o ProxyCommand='nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:6001 %h %p' username@remoteserver
```

Hope this helps!